# Python extract columns with repetitive headers with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, header

I have a csv file with 900000 rows and 30 columns. The header is in the first row:
"Probe Set ID","dbSNP RS ID","Chromosome","Physical Position", etc...

I want to extract only certain columns using pandas.

Now my problem is that the header repeats itself every 50 rows or so, so when I extract the columns I get only the first 50 rows. How can get the complete columns while skipping all the headers but the first one?

This is the code I have so far, but works nicely only until the second header:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('data1.csv', usecols = ['dbSNP RS ID', 'Physical         Position'])

import sys  
sys.stdout = open("data2.csv", "w") 
print data
```

This is an example representing some rows of the extracted columns:

```
      dbSNP RS ID       Physical Position
0        rs4147951          66943738
1        rs2022235          14326088
2        rs6425720          31709555
3       rs12997193         106584554
4        rs9933410          82323721
...
48       rs5771794          49157118
49       rs1061497           1415331
50      rs12647065         136012580

dbSNP RS ID             Physical Position
...
dbSNP RS ID             Physical Position
...
and so on...
```

Thanks very much in advance !

Answer (score 2):

You could [read the file with `header=None`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), [drop the duplicate rows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) (which keeps the first per default), and then set the remaining first row as header like so:

```
df = read_csv(path, header=None).drop_duplicates()
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, @Stefan Jansen !

Comment: Glad to hear my answer was useful.